# height:100% not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a question about the CSS property `height:100%` in Internet Explorer.

`height:100%` does not work in IE, but it does in Firefox and Chrome.

HTML File :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<html style="height:100%;">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu_neu">
        <ul id="topNav">
            <li class="current"><a href="#section-1">SECTION 1</b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section-2">SECTION 2 </b></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--SECTION- 1 .....................................................................................................................................-->
        <div class="section" id="section-1">SECTION - 1
            <div style="height:100%;" id="intro">
                <div class="story">
                    <div class="bg1"></div>
                    <div class="bg2"></div>
                    <div class="bg3"></div>
                    <div class="float-left" style="margin-top:120px; width:500px;">
                         <h2>HEIGHT 100% works in Chrome and Firefox,<br> <b>but not in IE!</b></h2>

                        <div id="s1Pfeil1" style="padding-top:120px;padding-left:255px;"> <a href="#second" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_down_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>

                        </div>
                        <!--/box-links-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/float-left-->
                </div>
                <!--./story-->
            </div>
            <!--/intro-->
            <div style="height:100%;" id="second">
                <div class="story">
                    <div class="bg1_2"></div>
                    <div class="bg2_2"></div>
                    <div class="bg3_2"></div>
                    <div class="float-right" style="margin-top:45px; width:500px;">
                            <h2>HEIGHT 100% works in Chrome and Firefox,<br> <b>but not in IE!</b></h2>

                        <div id="s1Pfeil2" style="padding-top:200px;padding-left:225px;">   <a href="#intro" title="Before Section"><img src="images/icon_up_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>  <a href="#third" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_down_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        </div>
                        <!--/box-links1-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/float-right-->
                </div>
                <!--./story-->
            </div>
            <!--#second-->
            <div id="third" style="height:100%;">
                <div class="story">
                    <div class="bg1_3"></div>
                    <div class="bg2_3"></div>
                    <div class="bg3_3"></div>
                    <div class="float-left" style="margin-top:80px; width:500px;">
                            <h2>HEIGHT 100% works in Chrome and Firefox,<br> <b>but not in IE!</b></h2>

                        <div id="s1Pfeil3" style="padding-top:200px;padding-left:225px;">   <a href="#second" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_up_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>

                        </div>
                        <!--/box-links2-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/float-left-->
                </div>
                <!--.story-->
            </div>
            <!--#third-->
        </div>
        <!--/section1-->
        <!--SECTION- 2 BRANDSTIFTER..................................................................................................................................-->
        <div class="section" id="section-2">SECTION -2
            <div id="intro_bs">
                <div class="story_bs">
                    <div class="bg1_bs"></div>
                    <div class="bg2_bs"></div>
                    <div class="bg3_bs"></div>
                    <div class="float-left_bs" style="margin-top:50px; width:600px;">
                            <h2>HEIGHT 100% works in Chrome and Firefox,<br> <b>but not in IE!</b></h2>

                        <div id="s2Pfeil1" style="padding-top:-50px;padding-left:305px;"> <a href="#second_bs" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_down_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>

                        </div>
                        <!--/box-links-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/float-left_bs-->
                </div>
                <!--.story-->
            </div>
            <!--#intro-->
            <div id="second_bs">
                <div class="story_bsc">
                    <div class="bg1_2_bs"></div>
                    <div class="bg2_2_bs"></div>
                    <div class="bg3_2_bs"></div>
                    <div class="float-right_bs" style="margin-top:120px; width:500px;">
                            <h2>HEIGHT 100% works in Chrome and Firefox,<br> <b>but not in IE!</b></h2>

                        <div id="s2Pfeil2" style="padding-top:80px;padding-left:305px;"><a href="#intro_bs" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_up_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#third_bs" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_down_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--.story-->
            </div>
            <!--#second-->
            <div id="third_bs">
                <div class="story_bsc">
                    <div class="bg1_3_bs"></div>
                    <div class="bg2_3_bs"></div>
                    <div class="bg3_3_bs"></div>
                    <div class="float-right_bs" style="margin-top:120px; width:500px;">
                            <h2>HEIGHT 100% works in Chrome and Firefox,<br> <b>but not in IE!</b></h2>

                        <div id="s2Pfeil3" style="padding-top:100px;padding-left:225px;">   <a href="#second_bs" title="Next Section"><img src="images/icon_up_normal.png" alt="Next" /></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--.story-->
            </div>
            <!--#third-->
        </div>
        <!--/section-2-->
    </div>
    <!--/wrapper-->
    <div class="suche">
        <form class="search" action="" method="post">
            <label for="search-box">Search:</label>
            <input id="search-box" type="text" name="search" onclick="search_bigger();" onblur="search_smaller();">
        </form> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/BrandortMarketingKommunikationsGmbh" title="Werde Fan von Brandort. auf Facebook" alt="Werde Fan von Brandort. auf Facebook" target="_blank"><div class="herz"></div></a><a href="images/icon_quicklinks_phone_hover_big.png" rel="lightbox" title="So erreichen Sie uns" alt="So erreichen Sie uns"><div class="telefon"></div></a>

    </div>
    <div class="css-panes">
        <div style="display: block;"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS File :

```
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    font-family: 'universal_light';
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:2em;
    background-color: #f6aa27;
    height: 100%;

}

p{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
}

p, ul{
    font-family:'universal_light';
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:16px;
}

img{
    border: 0;
}

h1, #pixels{
    font-family:"Museo 900", Verdana, serif;
    font-size-adjust:0.40;
    font-weight:700;
    font-style:normal;
}

h2{
    font-family: 'universal_black';
    color:#000000;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

#header h1, #pixels{
    color: #48941A;
}



#nav{
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
}

#nav li{
    margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
}

#nav_bs{
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
}

#nav_bs li{
    margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
}

#nav_bsa{
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
}

#nav_bsa li{
    margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
}

#header, #intro, #second{
    width: 100%;
}



/*hier wurde "fix" nach der "no-repeat" gelöscht*/
#intro{
    background-color:#f6aa27;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1200px;
    width:100%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;

}



/*hier wurde "fix" nach der "no-repeat" gelöscht*/
#intro .bg1{

    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -26px;
    margin-left: 66px;

}
/*hier wurde "fix" nach der "no-repeat" gelöscht*/
#intro .bg2{

    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#intro .bg3{
    background: url(images/kohle.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

#second{
    background:url(images/bg1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-color:#f6aa27;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}

#section-2{
background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

#second .bg1_2{
    background:url(images/second/feurig.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 143px;
    margin-top: -10px;

}

#second .bg2_2{
    background:url(images/second/handschrift.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

#second .bg3_2{
    background:url(images/second/brandeisen.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}


#third{
    background:url(images/bg1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-color:#f6aa27;
    color: #000000;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}

#third .bg1_3{
    background:url(images/third/handschrift.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#third .bg2_3{
    background:url(images/third/feurig.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#third .bg3_3{
    background:url(images/third/seil.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#fifth{
    background: #ccc;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}



#header, #intro_bs, #second_bs{
    width: 100%;
}

#intro_bs{
    background:url(images/bg2.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-color:#c9cacc;
    color: #000000;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
        border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;

}

#intro_bs .bg1_bs{
    background:url(images/intro_bs/mitarbeiter.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

#intro_bs .bg2_bs{
    background:url(images/intro_bs/feurig.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#intro_bs .bg3_bs{
    background:url(images/intro_bs/handschrift.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#second_bs{
    background:url(images/bg2.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-color:#c9cacc;
    color: #000000;
    height: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}

#second_bs .bg1_2_bs{
    background:url(images/second_bs/feurig.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

#second_bs .bg2_2_bs{
    background:url(images/second_bs/handschrift.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}

#second_bs .bg3_2_bs{
    background:url(images/second_bs/steffen.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -121px;


}


#third_bs{
    background:url(images/bg2.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-color:#c9cacc;
    color: #000000;
    height: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}

#third_bs .bg1_3_bs{
    background:url(images/third_bs/feurig.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#third_bs .bg2_3_bs{
    background:url(images/third_bs/handschrift.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;

}
#third_bs .bg3_3_bs{
    background:url(images/third_bs/mike.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: -121px;
    margin-top: -287px;
}




.story{
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 980px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 980px;

}

.story .float-left, .story .float-right{
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;   
}


.linkp1 a {
    background:url('images/brandort_norm.gif') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
    /*height: 12px;
    width: 95px;*/
    display: block;
    z-index:11111;
}

.linkp1 a:hover {
    background:url('images/brandort_hover.gif') 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
}


.linkp2 a {
    background:url('images/brandstifter_norm.gif') no-repeat fixed;
    /*height: 12px;
    width: 95px;*/
    display: block;
    z-index:11111;
}

.linkp2 a:hover {
    background:url('images/brandstifter_hover.gif') no-repeat fixed;
}

.linkp3 a {
    background:url('images/brandsaetze_norm.gif') no-repeat fixed;
    /*height: 12px;
    width: 95px;*/
    display: block;
    z-index:11111;
}

.linkp3 a:hover {
    background:url('images/brandsaetze_hover.gif') no-repeat fixed;
}

.linkp4 a {
    background:url('images/brandschaetze_norm.gif') no-repeat fixed;
    /*height: 12px;
    width: 95px;*/
    display: block;
    z-index:11111;
}

.linkp4 a:hover {
    background:url('images/brandschaetze_hover.gif') no-repeat fixed;
}

.linkp5 a {
    background:url('images/brandpunkt_norm.gif') no-repeat fixed;
    /*height: 12px;
    width: 95px;*/
    display: block;
    z-index:11111;
}

.linkp5 a:hover {
    background:url('images/brandpunkt_hover.gif') no-repeat fixed;
}




#menu_neu {
height: 40px;
width: 1200px;
text-align: center;
line-height:1em!important;
position: fixed;
left: 40%;
width: 640px;
z-index: 10000;
}

ul#topNav{
    margin-top:51px;
    margin-left: -218px;
    color:#000000;
}

ul#topNav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50%;
}

ul#topNav a, ul#topNav span {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.4em;
    margin-left: 0.1em;
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:14px;
}

* html ul#topNav a, * html ul#topNav span {  /* Korrektur fuer IE 5.x */
    width: 8em;
    wi\dth: 6em;
}

ul#topNav a:hover, ul#topNav span {
    color:#000000;
    font-size:14px;
}

ul#topNav a:active {
    color:#000000;
    font-size:14px;
}

ul#topNav div {
     clear: left;
}

#topNav .current a {
    color:#F45D32;
}
```

Demo : http://ealtinel.com/height/

How can I get it to work in IE?

Comment: Your first `<meta>` should go inside the `<head>` as well!

Comment: i have changed, but it works not:(

Comment: make html, body {height:100%} and mark rest height:auto; (Ex: #wrapper{height: auto;}) in your css

Comment: Where is your **doctype** ?

Comment: @aldimeola1122 yes, put `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the beggining. [Example](http://jsbin.com/exayom/2/edit)

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://ealtinel.com/height
it works not in IE

Comment: Hi Aldimeola....your problem is with your image tag, (Ex: <img src="images/icon_down_normal.png" alt="Next" />). In IE its working fine if i remove the image tag...Problem in positioning the image.

Answer (score 40):

In IE, in order for an element to have `height:100%;`, all parent elements must have `height:100%;`. Any break in the "chain" will cause IE to ignore everything.

It should work if your css includes the following:

```css
html,body { height:100%; } 
#wrapper { height:100%; }
.section { height:100%; }
```

I've opened your page in IE and applied these changes using the developers tools and can verify that it works.

Comment: @aldimeola1122 you need to put `#wrapper{ height:100%; }` back in

Answer (score 15):

In order to use `height: 100%`, the parent container should have a fixed height.

So for example while this should work:

```
<div style="height: 400px;">
    <div style="height: 100%; background: red; float: left; width: 200px;">
        Left Column
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%; margin-left: 210px;">
        Right Column
    </div>
</div>
```

The following will not work:

```
<div style="height: 100%;">
    --- same code
</div>
```

One way to achieve a fixed height when you don't know parent's height is using `position: absolute;`.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 200px; background: red;">
        Left Column
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 210px;">
        Right Column
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you could use javascript as noted in the other answer. But I prefer pure CSS solutions.

[Check here for a live fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rDzcz/1/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @aldimeola1122 sorry I missed your comment... I just seen it but the link is dead.

Comment: @LaraBelle I guess that browser was dead 10 years ago:)

Comment: @SavasVedova not on my Senior Dev. He wants everything to be supported.

Comment: @LaraBelle, sorry, I dont have the tools to test ie 6. Maybe you should try setting up height 100% of every parent or you can use javascript to set the height (guess this is an easier solution).

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work. You have to make the parent html and the child to have the same attributes.In some cases you have to use pixels in order to make it function.

```
html,body, \\ this has to go to every element you want to have a height 100% 
{
  height:100%;
}
```

I also have something nice

```
window.onload=function(){
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){ \\ to detect if the browser used by the client is IE
winHight = window.innerHeight
document.getElementById("mainContainer").setAttribute('style',"height:"+winHeight+";");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a same problem with one of my project as well but couldn't find the solution as `width: 100%` was working but not `height`. So I used a little trick to wrap my page inside a `div` and update div's height with javascript.

```
windowHeight = window.innerHeight
document.getElementById("mainContainer").setAttribute('style',"height:"+windowHeight+";");
```

And linked that to an event.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but it still might be useful to some people. I had a problem with an image on IE. The image had the property "max-width:100%", and it would work perfectly on Chrome, but not at all on IE.

What I simply did to the image is put a width AND a max-width.
It would be something like :

```
 img.logo {
        width:100%;
        max-width:1600px;
    }
```

And it worked for me :D`

`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enter the height property, it will be sized proportionally to the width.
style="height: 25%;  width: 25%; object-fit: contain" doesn't work in IE
**style="width: 25%; object-fit: contain" works in IE and sized height at 25%**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

border-bottom: 1px solid /* any color that match to your design */

Answer (score -1):

I tried a few things out and this seems to be the solution:

Add the following meta-tag in the head-section of your html-document:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" >
```

It seems as if the IE automatically turns on the compatibility mode for (IE) Version 7. This meta-tag forces IE to set the compatibility mode to Version 10 of IE. This solution only work in IE Version 10 or higher.

Good Luck!