# Google maps not working IE11

Tags: google-maps

I've just noticed `Google Maps` isn't working in `IE 11`, but works completely fine in `Chrome` and `Firefox`. Is there something obvious that I overlooked to get it to work? You can check for a live version here: [link](http://speyer.clouddesign.be/contact.php)

```
function initialize() {


var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.035113, 3.715104);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    icon: "img/marker.png"
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) works fine for me on IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because of the style sheet.

According to [this website](http://www.easypagez.eu/maps/ieworking.html),

> IE needs to know the size of the map ensure that it has been set

if you took out the style sheet for [this sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple), it would stop working under IE. And I would assume the same issue caused your problem.

Comment: Yes indeed, that seems to work, thanks. However, I'm working with 100% both width and height and that makes it disappear again.

Comment: Nevermind, `width:100%;height:100%` with a ´position:relative;` works fine! Thanks again

Comment: Welcome :) Let's just hopes the new IE gets better :)

Comment: @kaho, please note that the link given in the answer is broken.

Comment: thanks, you can visit it via https://web.archive.org/web/20160305164818/http://www.easypagez.eu/maps/ieworking.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated by kaho, this issue is related to the styling. Your map had no specified height and width, and would therefore not appear. But even if you specified the `height` and `width` using CSS percentages, it doesn't appear in IE11 due to its behavior regarding the container of the map `div`. Specifically, if you want to get a full-sized map on IE11, you must specify `height:100%` and `width:100%` on all containing elements, including `body` and `html`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811716/height100-not-working-in-internet-explorer) question for a related discussion.