# Internet Explorer height: 100% not producing same result as Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813167/667903) I've set all parent containers of the `img` icons in the Services menu of [this site](https://www.orsgroup.com.au/) in order to prevent the icons from displaying smaller than in Chrome.

In Chrome (correct):

[image]

In IE 10 (mostly incorrect):

[image]

The IE specific stylesheet I use is:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/themes/nevada-child/css/ie.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

containing:

```
html, body, #wrap, #nav-wrap, #nav-wrap .container, .ubermenu, .ubermenu-nav, .ubermenu-submenu, .ubermenu-item, .ubermenu-target {height: 100%;}
```

However, the `img` icons still display small.

There is CSS in the main stylesheet:

```
.ubermenu .ubermenu-image:not(.ubermenu-image-lazyload) {
    height: auto;
}
```

yet the icons in IE all seem to display at the same height as the service heading: e.g. `<span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Employment Services</span>`

I hate the IE inspector and have difficulty using it.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Why not set their height as `1em` in that case? Instead of `auto`?

Comment: In Chrome, the `img` icons display as the client is happy with, and they're adapting to the containing `<a class="ubermenu-target>`'s height, rather than a static height.

Comment: `auto` wouldn't fulfil either of those requirements, it just implies the standard height for the image. They probably all appear the same height _because thats their natural height_.

Comment: Right. The inline width and height are 10px. Why does Chrome enlarge them? I can't see a CSS rule which does this. And why does IE not behave the same way?

Comment: When I view it in chrome, it is not enlarged. The solution I have below is tested only in chrome. Haven't tested in IE.

Comment: Thanks. Works in IE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are making the images a `width` of `10px` and a `height` of `10px` within your image tags. If you control your html you can remove these and it should work fine. If you only control the css just add `width: auto;` to the following:

```
.ubermenu .ubermenu-image:not(.ubermenu-image-lazyload) {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, images don't really adhere to that definition of width height unless as a last resort (like no mention of them _at all_ in CSS).

Comment: So why does adding `width: auto;` tells the browser to make the `img` larger? Is the browser interpreting that as an instruction to display the `img` in its actual size?

Comment: Good question. I've posted a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952824/css-overriding-width-and-height-attribute-why).