# Body height ist not 100% in Edge / Internet Explorer / Firefox

Tags: html, css

i already found this thread ([height:100% not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811716/height100-not-working-in-internet-explorer)) but in my case i just can't find the solution.

If you view the page in chrome, everthing is fine, but the html in IE and Edge is just as big as the screen resolution.

You can see the problem live at http://www.bf-com.net

Comment: changed 
`html {
    height: 100%;
}`
to
`html {
    min-height: 100%;
}`
and now the html height is 100% in all browsers, but the body height isn't

Comment: try to give height in **viewport height(vh)** height:100vh

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by

```
html,body { height: 100vh;}
```

Thanks to Abhishek!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use THis 
  html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;

 }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.