# .svg image on IE11 , height property does not work, but max-height does

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height

I have a .svg logo that I need to display on my page and found that it does not appear right on IE11. its scaled and just a part of it appears , whereas other browsers display correctly. I changed its height property to max-height and it looks fine now. I could not find a proper explanation as to why that happened. Will anybody be able to help me here

CSS which did not work in IE

```
.svglogo {
  height:70px;
}
```

CSS which worked

```
.svglogo {
  max-height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In IE 11 for height property, instead of giving in `pixels` try giving it in `%`, also if at all there is a parent element it should also have a height that is in `%`, if there is a break in the chain then it won't work.
[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813167/4877962) 
You can add browser-specific property for ie in your css and give the `max-height` for that class, which will also solve the problem.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
     /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
}
```

Also, remember that always try to give the in `%` or `em` so that when the browser resizes, the logo won't get distorted.
You can also try this:

```
.svglogo {
  height:70px !important;
}
```

Comment: But I did not have a percentage in there. it was just height:100px that did not work

Comment: Try giving height:70px !important;

Comment: no. !imprtant did not work. I did find a solution. Changing height to max-height worked and its showing fine now, All I need is a reason for why 'max-height' is working and not 'height'